A word for not just optional but usually not done
Is there a word for a sort of "Even more optional than optional" - i.e.
If an action is optional, you can choose not to do it if you want.
However, is there a word which emphasises that not only is an action optional, but doing it is the unusual case?
Sample Sentence:

At next week's marathon, walking is optional, carrying a fridge on your back is ______

Edit for more context
I'm creating a form with a list of tasks. Each task can be specified as either mandatory, optional (but you have to give a reason for not doing it) or optional (feel free to ignore it, in fact we don't expect you to do it at all.. but you might).
As such, a word for "optional but you have to give a reason" would likely be as useful but I know SE doesn't really like these "multiple answer" type questions.
And I don't want to use the word "ignorable".  (So maybe my marathon sentence wasn't the best example)

A sample sentence for your remote option?

I think the question is based on the flawed premise that optional has some implication for how often the option is exercised. You can't naturally contrast unqualified optional with some term that means optional, but very rarely exercised. I suggest the example should be amended to ...walking is a relatively common option, but carrying a fridge on your back is a very unlikely option.

@FumbleFingers - I know "optional" doesn't specify how often the option is exercised. But words being what they are, they can carry implications beyond their strict definitions (e.g. there is a difference between "big" and "ginormous" even though the word "big" doesn't have a limit on how big the thing is) and I was hoping there was a word, similar to "optional" but that really kind of means "well, you can do it if you like, but we really don't expect you to".

Would unrecommemded do?

@user405662 - that feels a bit like "we'd rather you didn't" - which is not what I'm trying to convey, which is, for want of a better way of putting it... kind of very optional

What you want is a word that means "you can opt out of this requirement but you must give a reason".  You don't need a word that means "optional (but rarely chosen)".  That tidbit of extra information in the parentheses is risible.

Sharia has "5 rulings", roughly: must, prerable, neutral, disfavored, must not. Halakha has nuanced categories, too. Apathetic, agnostic, or the a- prefix could be useful, compare with apolitical and amoral. Perhaps: required; with approval; at your discretion.

"... an abnormal thing to do even though it's technically not against the rules"?

In your use case, 'allowed' might work?  e.g.  Mandatory, Optional, Allowed - Although it would be more usual to just list the mandatory and optional.  If you feel you have a need for the third column, then it may be better  to list e.g. Mandatory, optional(credit), optional(no credit given).

How about "unconventional" or "unorthodox".

Not single words but I can't resist given the example context -- "go the extra mile", also "go over and above", likely to be rightly taken as tongue-in-cheek there.

One way to slightly humourously refer to something that is permitted and sometimes done, but is something that most people would not wish to do for obvious reasons, and will not be penalised for not doing, would be strictly optional.

At next week's marathon, walking is optional, carrying a fridge on your back is strictly optional!

The tension between "strictness" and the permissiveness of something being "optional" leads to it being a slightly tongue-in-cheek way of putting it. Depending on how the deadpan the delivery is, it may or may not have an exclamation mark and/or emphasis on the "strictly".
If you think it might not be obvious enough for your audience, you could also use completely/absolutely optional.

For comparison/contrast, although they are probably best considered a dialect and not 'regular' English, documents about Internet standards, protocols, and methods -- by custom always titled "Request For Comments" (RFC) even though most don't actually request comments -- have a standard wording for this documented in RFC 2119 aka Best Current Practice (BCP) 14. The keywords are (again customarily) always in caps and are:
MUST (NOT) or SHALL (NOT) or REQUIRED means just that: it is mandatory (or prohibited)
SHOULD (NOT) or RECOMMENDED means follow the spec unless you have a good reason to do otherwise
MAY or OPTIONAL is a free choice: do it or not as you prefer
Note in normal English 'may not' usually means 'not permitted/allowed' and thus actually prohibited, which is likely why the RFC doesn't define "MAY NOT".

The RFC does not actually prescribe a meaning for MAY NOT; due to the potential ambiguity it should be avoided entirely (e.g. by rephrasing "MAY choose to not" or similar).

Agree with Miral: it may be clearer for this question to omit the negatives and just define MUST/SHOULD/MAY.


mandatory  optional  uncommon

It is an uncommon but possible occurrence:

not seen, happening, or experienced often

Accidents due to failure of safety equipment are uncommon nowadays [but that does not mean they do not happen]. (Cambridge)


And since it's uncommon, it is not really expected as a requirement.
As for the optional which requires the reason for not carrying it out, the adjective accountable came to my mind. It can mean

able to be explained (Collins)

It may not be the right term, but it may give a direction to your quest for the right term.

You don't need a word that means "optional (but rarely chosen)".  What you want is a word that means "if you opt out of this one you must give a reason". The word doesn't exist. You will have to use a bunch of smaller words and make a sentence.
Mandatory
Discretionary (but you must provide a reason if you choose not to do it)
Optional

A useful metaphor would be "extra credit". The literal meaning of this is an assignment in a class which a student may do to get additional credit towards their grade (or if they already have a perfect grade, it will just be a way to learn more for personal improvement), but there's no penalty for not doing it.
As a metaphor you can use it for any effort above or beyond the normal and optional activities.

Extra credit for running the race with a fridge on your back.


"Extra credit" makes it seem like it's better to do it anyway. Is there an expression that means "technically allowed, but does not give any credit even if you do it"?

Possibly, but the usual context is "if the normal assignment isn't enough (or too easy) for you, you can add this". The credit is there to make it a useful use of your time.

How about "No extra credit for running the race with a fridge on your back."?

For a task list:

Mandatory
Optional

I'd probably switch this for "declinable", "advisable", or "highly suggested"; if you choose one then "optional" can be the third option


Elective


Addressing the issue with your specific example:
Sarcasm does not translate well in writing.
Offering a tongue-in-cheek option will always imply that this specific thing has some sort of merit/history in the aforementioned task.
It may be funny for those on the inner-circle but would be confusing for newcomers.
Before you know it, you are hosting the "Fridge-back Marathon" due to the literal level that participants are willing to take the absurdity.

At next week's marathon, walking is optional, carrying a fridge on your back is inadvisable.

Sarcasm works just as terribly with a different suggestion:

At next week's marathon, walking is optional, releasing a swarm of wasps at the starting line is inadvisable.


Pretty sure "inadvisable" is standard English for "this is a bad idea, but you do you", where "unadvisable" is far less common and when it's used, it's more neutral (it's more "cannot give advice" vs. "inadvisable" meaning "this is a bad idea").

@ShadowRanger Thanks! Those pesky vowels' proximity on the keyboard won that round =)

I don't think there are any options that fully capture what you want, but I would use "unnecessary". I think this gives the impression that I expect you won't do it (but I don't mind if you do).

One more possibility in certain contexts could be

requesting a room with a small herd of sheep is discouraged

This would fit the OP's qualification "optional but you have to give a reason". I would expect this qualification if servicing the option is difficult, time-consuming or costly for the provider. It is, however, a possible option because it is mentioned.

This would be my choice as well, noting that OP specifically asked for a single word.

Perhaps "possible" would fit in this context?
This conveys that it is not mandatory, but it also gives the impression that it is not the norm.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You could borrow the classification from the HIPAA Security Rule implementation specifications:

required -- must be implemented,
addressable -- may not be implemented, but the reason must be documented,
optional (not in HIPAA) -- what it says.

If addressable doesn't sound pleasant to your ear (it doesn't to mine), you could replace it with something synonymous, like needs attention.

I will agree with some of the other answers here that "middle" word is really the one that is hardest to condense into a single word without clarification. With that being said the word I would recommend for the "optional (feel free to ignore it, in fact we don't expect you to do it at all.. but you might)" would be:
Voluntary

1: proceeding from the will or from one's own choice or consent
(e.g., a voluntary action, voluntary cooperation)
2: unconstrained by interference:  SELF-DETERMINING
(e.g., a voluntary participant)

So your list could look like this:

Mandatory
Optional (provide reason for not completing)
Voluntary


People seem to be hung up on getting "optional" as the second level, but I think it works best as the third:

Mandatory
Recommended
Optional


I was going to suggest "Required", "Desired" and "Permissible" but this is good.

Carrying a fridge on your back would be unorthodox. The meaning, breaking with convention or tradition, may suit your question. Convention and tradition themselves are quite optional to begin with, but many feel societal pressure to continue them without good reason for breaking them.

I like unorthodox... it has the permissible-but-you-really-think-you-should? vibe. I was thinking untraditional or non-traditional.

Depending on your context, it could be more clear to use terminology as described by the MoSCoW method
Instead of using mandatory, optional, ??; you can use must, should, could, won't.

The words that most immediately come to mind are gratuitous, extraneous, redundant and superfluous.
In this context all of these words imply what is not only not necessary, but also deemed so unnecessary as to be worth calling out as existing almost purely for its own sake.
You could triangulate the meaning more finely and give it nuance with words having slightly different connotations, if the "optional" thing is technically or customarily called for but is not actually vital, such as token, or perfunctory. In referring to outdated traditions, rules or regulations, a valid term could be vestigial.

I am not sure if this would be the appropriate context, but NASA has a well written workmanship standard (for contractors to follow), that uses the words "Preferred", "Acceptable", and "Unacceptable".
https://workmanship.nasa.gov/lib/insp/2%20books/frameset.html
Carrying a refrigerator on your back would be acceptable (but no one would do it on purpose).

Please include the information from the link in your answer as a quote.  Links can rot, and answers ought not : )

You could go with the 3 R's:

Required
Recommended
Rare


Lots of good suggestions here. I'd agree with most that optional means just that and does not imply that you have to give a reason when you choose not to - so it already means the third thing.
With terms like elective the problem is that the items themselves are optional, but you may be required to do at least X of them. A good general word for the middle way might be negotiable.
Where I used to teach some courses were presented to the students as "unusual options" - which meant getting credit in a subject taught outside of our department (so a small bit of your Maths BSc might be earned learning beginners' German, e.g.) or in a rather advanced topic outside the usual BSc scope.
In Britain we also have the parliamentary tradition of whip, two-line whip, three-line whip. Especially the latter, also known as triple whip, have entered general parlance. It means "you don't have to, but then there will be hell to pay if you don't."

A phrase that's sometimes used is ‘a custom more honoured in the breach than in the observance’.
That's from Hamlet Act 1 Scene IV, and people usually take it to mean something positive but rarely done, especially if it has become less popular than it used to be.
However, that's actually a misunderstanding of Shakespeare's Early Modern English; Hamlet is really saying that the custom (of drinking and carousing loudly at night) is more honourable when not performed — that he disapproves of the custom and thinks it would be better to abandon it.
So it's probably better to avoid that phrase, to prevent misunderstandings.
